# WPF Toolkit Chart : Column Series not plotting if itemsSource less than 2

Tags: wpf, charts, toolkit

I am using VS2008 and WPF Toolkit to build a chart

The problem is when using LinearAxis with ColumnSeries it is only plotting if the itemsSource count is bigger than 1, If i removed the LinearAxis from the chart it will plot the data even if the itemsSource Count is 1.

Here is my code :

```
        ColumnSeries colmSer2 = new ColumnSeries();
        colmSer2.ItemsSource = ThierdChartList; // List Of (Freq,Count) Freq >=12 && Freq<18
        colmSer2.DependentValueBinding = new Binding("COUNT");
        colmSer2.IndependentValueBinding = new Binding("FREQ");


        HistogramChart2.Series.Add(colmSer2);

        LinearAxis lAxes3 = new LinearAxis();
        lAxes3.Orientation = AxisOrientation.X;
        lAxes3.Interval = .5;
        lAxes3.Minimum = 12;
        lAxes3.Maximum = 18;
        HistogramChart2.Axes.Add(lAxes3);
```

All the Frequency data in ThierdChartList are Freq >= 12 & Freq<18

Thanks in advance 
Majed

Comment: Yes, it displays 1 column, but what you expected? Anyway you can check the number of points before binding and display a no data indicator if there is only one point, but it isn't as logical as the current behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If it's acceptable, you can check if there is one point in data collection before binding it to the chart. If there is only one item, you can add additional "fake" point with value of *0*.

I was looking for an answer for your question, but I've found similar question that was asked here: 
*[WPF Toolkit (February 2010 release) Chart with Column Series empty when ItemsSource has only one item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762455/wpf-toolkit-february-2010-release-chart-with-column-series-empty-when-itemssou)*.

Comment: Hi Lucas, First of all thanks for answering my question i tried what you said but the problem the column width will tack the hole chart size.

Comment: Have you tried adding more fake points on both sides of the point with an actual value? It should make the bar thinner.